# DevExpress TabPages - Getting Current Tab Page

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I've been looking around the web for an answer to this, But I cant seem to figure it out. I need to know which tab page is the current selected page. But DevExpress's documentation's been confusing me and there's no relevant answer in visual basic.

I know I need to use the tabpage changed event, which I have shown below, but I'm not sure on the syntax for checking to see if tabpage 2 is the current selected/open page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub XtraTabControl1_SelectedPageChanging(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangingEventArgs) Handles XtraTabControl1.SelectedPageChanging

    'If Current tabpage = tabpage 2 Then
       'Do something
    'end if 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`XtraTabControl.SelectedTabPage`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedTabPagetopic) property to get the current tab page.

```
If xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage Is XtraTabPage2 Then
   'Do something
End If
```

But if you want to get current tab page in [`XtraTabControl.SelectedPageChanging`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedPageChangingtopic) event then you can use `e.PrevPage` property.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub XtraTabControl1_SelectedPageChanging(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangingEventArgs) Handles XtraTabControl1.SelectedPageChanging

    If e.PrevPage Is XtraTabPage2 Then
       'Do something
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to use this, for some reason the suggestions had an error ONLY when placed in the IF statement - something about the '=' symbol not being a member of the XtraTabControl1. Buts this worked:

```
 If XtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage.Equals(XtraTabPage2) Then
            'Do something
            MsgBox("Tabpage2")
        End If
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you want to compare object references, then in vb.net you must use the [`Is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) operator. I've updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936636/1805640).

Answer (score 0):

I believe e.Page should let you know what page called the event.